# Is there a pricing for using multiple threads to send data to a AWS SQS queue at the exact same moment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, httprequest, amazon-sqs

Let's say an HTTP request posts data to a AWS SQS queue. In case if there are like 300 of these requests at the same time or maybe 3000 requests at the same time. Is this chargeable like for more than 300 requests in a sec AWS can charge extra? If so then realistically how many messages can we send to SQS without incurring any extra charges?

I didn't try anything since it might get my company charges.

Comment: Nothing in this question is related to MuleSoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Amazon SQS Pricing | Message Queuing Service | AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/) is simply **per million requests**. There is no charge based on the number of "requests per second" used. Amazon SQS is a fully-managed service that simultaneously handles requests from all customers in a Region so it is designed to handle extremely high volumes of requests.

However, as noted on [Amazon SQS FAQs | Message Queuing Service | AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/):

> FIFO queues support up to 3,000 messages per second with batching or up to 300 messages per second (300 send, receive, or delete operations per second) without batching. If you require higher throughput, you can enable high throughput mode for FIFO on the Amazon SQS console, which will support up to 70,000 messages per second without batching and even higher with batching.

There does not seem to be a charge for using [High throughput for FIFO queues - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/high-throughput-fifo.html) aside from the normal per-request charge.

Please note that 'requests' include:

- Sending messages
- Receiving messages
- Deleting messages

So, processing a single message might require multiple 'requests' to the Amazon SQS service.

Comment: Thanks you very much @JohnRotenstein for the quick answer. I just wanted to make sure that I understood your words correctly. So you are saying that my interface can **concurrently** publish/write 300 to 3000 or more messages (at same miliseconds/seconds) to a non FIFO SQS or SNS without any additional charges. Please confirm.

Comment: That is correct. There is no charge related to the number of "messages per second". Charging is based only on the number of requests made during the month.